# EXE program calling aspx page gets: 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating an executable program that uses `HttpClient` to call a URL. I try using the `DefaultNetworkCredentials` as I do not know the user id and password of the server. The following code runs successfully on my local machine, but it will get error when deployed to the server.

[image]

My code:

```
HttpClientHandler authtHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
};

// Call the URL                    
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(authtHandler))
{
    var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("testingkey", "testingvalue")
    });

    // Make it sync instead of async by using .Result
    var result = httpClient.PostAsync(url, formContent).Result;

    // Get the content, for verification 
    var content = result.Content;
}
```

Comment: Does the web page work if called by the web browser?

Comment: @AntonioPetricca Yes

Comment: Did you try NOT passing an HttpClientHandler instance to the HttpClient constructor?

Comment: Yes, initially I did not pass the credential and I get the authorization error. Then I tried passing it but I still get the error.

Comment: Could you try to simulate the same call by WGET in order to check if the issue is related to your client code or server misconfiguration?

Comment: What do you mean simulate the same call by WGET? I tried using postman and make a GET/POST call and is able to access the page.

Comment: POSTMAN is the same! Please could you try changing "CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials" with "CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials"?

Comment: Changing to `DefaultCredentials` gave the same error.

Answer (score 2):

DefaultNetworkCredentials is the authentication credentials for the current security context in which the application is running. For client side application, these are usually the Windows credentials of the user who is running the application.

If the user does not have rights over the URL over what you are using the HttpClient then error will come. To make it work you

1. either have to impersonate the user who has access over that
   application or
2. run your EXE using system defined accounts like Network
   Service credentials and ensure that HTTP application can be accessed
   using the same.

Comment: Tried running the exe as an admin account but it still does not work. Is there any other approach?